# Image analysis about area

Tags: arcgis-pro, area, ndvi, image-analysis

I tried to find out the lake's area in an image raster - I used NDVI and reclassify then I got a whole value file like this.

Is there anyone can tell me how to divide them to each polygon?

Or I can only analyse this with a whole part?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be to use the **[Raster to Polygon](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/raster-to-polygon.htm)** tool. I would first use a tool like **[Con](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/con-.htm)** which will allow you to save the lakes to a separate raster. That way, when you convert to Polygon, you're only converting the lakes.

Finally, when you have your polygons, if your output file format supports it, the area will be calculated automatically as an attribute using the coordinate system of the data. Alternatively, you can calculate the geometry or use **[python](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field-examples.htm)** to calculate the Area.